# Unable to start .jar file as a window service

Tags: jar, windows-services

I've got a jar file which contains a very simple program of displaying "Hello" message in the console. I want to run this jar file as a windows service.  This service gets started without any hiccup (I'm using Tanuki's Java Service Wrapper), however, it simply wouldn't start the service.

Below is the error I'm facing

> wrapper  | The Hello Sample Application service was launched, but failed to start.
>   wrapper  | Please check the log file more information: C:\wrapper-windows-x86-32
>   -3.5.14\logs\wrapper.log
>   Press any key to continue . . .**

Comment: Did you check the log file? Please post the content so that we can see why the service didn't start.

Comment: Hi @coding.mof, belw is the excerpt of log file..FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/06/29 18:47:56 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2012/06/29 18:47:56 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.

Comment: Might it be that your program directly returns/exits? Could you please post your code? It seems to me that your program has to keep on running after it has been started as service - othwise it wouldn't make sense to wrap it into a service. ;) Try to modify your program so that it keeps on running...

Comment: @coding.mof... the prog:import java.io.*;

class Hello
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

System.out.print("Hello");
}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your program so that it keeps running. If not the service wrapper will terminate and windows will see a service that is supposed to be running but doesn't.
Try something like:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    try {
      while(true){
        System.out.println("Hello Service World.");

        // Sleep - Otherwise we would eat up all CPU
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStacktrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Or start another thread and perform your service's work. ;)

Comment: Hi, I tried running the above code as a service but in vain..M still stuck up wid the same problem.Further, when i tried starting this service from task manager I get "Operation could not be completed..access denied".I'm using window 7.I thot this mite b access rite problem so i ran this service through cmd as a administrator using sc command.however still it refuses to start...I'm beginning to wonder could this be a problem related to configuration file i have edited?